# php exports to cvs, but something happens that makes the csv totally unusable

Tags: php, excel, zend-framework, csv, magento-1.4

I export every day the sales of yesterday (Magento) by a custom phpscript.

Since we got directbanking i had to change the code a bit.
The idea was to set the value "direct" in the CC_Type(Visa,JBC,...) so that we have good looking data for our analytics.

The csv looks actually clean and when i do a manually import (where you customize the import) with excel or mssql it works as wished. But when i let it open by it self (like our system would do to import the data in the night) strange things happen.

[image: screenshot of excel with open document]

- In the data-/functionbar (fx) you can see that the curser is ON the D and if I insert more letters they are appendet AFTER the p from onlineshop.
- the *header (first line)* and every following dataline become imported without the **""**, I know that excel sometimes does this, but it never did before with this document.
  Well thats a lie i never payed attation if it is so or not, because it simply worked.

//

```
class Mage_Shell_Compiler extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {
const OUTPUT = false;
const DEL = "\t";
const BR = "\r\n";
const FILEPATH = '../var/export/';
const FILENAME = 'tdtaCash';

protected $_orders = array();
protected $_csv_output = '';
protected $_headers = array(
    "dtTag" => false, // Bestelldatum
    "fiCBox" => 94,
    "fiCashier" => "onlineshop",
    "fiCurrency" => array('Visa', 'MC', 'Amex', 'DC', 'JCB', 'Direct'), // Zahlungsart
    "dtRev" => false  // Bruttoumsatz an diesem Tag mit dieser Zahlungsart
);

/// @see $_headers for details
protected function addOrderToRows($order, $rows) {
    $order_data = $order->getOrigData();
    $type = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation('CC_BRAND');

    switch ($type) {
        case 'VISA':
            $type = 'Visa';
            break;
        case 'MasterCard':
            $type = 'MC';
            break;
        case 'American Express':
            $type = 'Amex';
            break;
        case 'Diners Club':
            $type = 'DC';
            break;
        case 'JCB':
            $type = 'JCB';
            break;
        default:
            $brand = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation('BRAND');
            if ($brand == 'DirectEbankingAT') {
                $type = 'Direct';
            }
            break;
    }

    if (empty($rows[$type])) {
        $row = $this->_headers;
        $row["dtRev"] = 0;
    } else
        $row = $rows[$type];

    //$row['dtTag']       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($order_data['created_at']));
    $row['dtTag'] = $this->formatDate($order_data['created_at'], 'exportdate', true);
    $row["fiCurrency"] = $type;
    $row["dtRev"] += $order_data['grand_total'];

    $rows[$type] = $row;

    return $rows;
}

protected function __($msg) {
    if (self::OUTPUT)
        print $msg . "\n";
}

/**
 * Get Orders instance
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
 */
protected function _getOrders($day = 1) {
    $timeZoneOffset = Mage::getModel('core/date')->getGmtOffset();
    $yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$day day")) . ' 00:00:00';
    $yesterday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($yesterday) - $timeZoneOffset);
    $day--;
    $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$day day")) . ' 00:00:00';
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($today) - $timeZoneOffset);
    if (!$this->_orders)
        $this->_orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                /// @note uncommented to remove daily filter
                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array("from" => $yesterday, "to" => $today))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('holded', 'canceled', 'pending_payment', 'pending')));
    return $this->_orders;
}

protected function addRowToOutput($row) {
    if (isset($row["dtRev"]))
        $row["dtRev"] = number_format($row["dtRev"], 2);
    $this->_csv_output .= '"' . implode('"' . self::DEL . '"', $row) . '"' . self::BR;
}

protected function addCsvHeader() {
    $this->addRowToOutput(array_keys($this->_headers));
}

/**
 * Run script
 *
 */
public function run() {
    if ($this->getArg('export')) {
        $day = is_numeric($this->getArg('day')) ? $this->getArg('day') : 1;
        $file = self::FILEPATH . self::FILENAME . '.csv';
        $this->__('orders to export ' . count($this->_getOrders($day)));
        // add header if file is empty
        if (!strlen(trim(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file))))
            $this->addCsvHeader();
        $rows = array();
        foreach ($this->_getOrders($day) as $order)
            $rows = $this->addOrderToRows($order, $rows);
        while ($row = array_shift($rows))
            $this->addRowToOutput($row);
        file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file, $this->_csv_output, FILE_APPEND);
        $this->__($this->_csv_output);
    } else {
        echo $this->usageHelp();
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieve Usage Help Message
 *
 */
public function usageHelp() {
    return <<<USAGE
    Usage:  php -f export_tdtaCash.php -- [options]
    export  ...  Appends data to file tdtaCash.csv in Directory var/export/
    day     ...  days to count back
    help    ...  This help
USAGE;
    }

}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_Compiler();
$shell->run();
```

So my question is, may someone can explain me what kind of sourcery is responsable for this effect, and what can i do preventive to not get such results again?!

**EDIT:**
here is a screenshot of the CSV opend in Notepad++
[image: screenshot of opend CSV in Notepad++]

Comment: What does the *actual CSV* look like, the textual data? Let's completely forget how *Excel* interprets this data, because Excel really isn't the best product to judge any data by.

Comment: looks completly normal in notepad++ ...

Answer (score 2):

Change file resolution from `CSV` to `TXT` and use `Import file`, specify `TAB` character as separator - and you'll be fine!

Comment: If you're importing the file manually anyway, there's no need to change the extension.

Comment: @deceze for my Excel 2007 it just opens CSV as on OP screen.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a ***C*** SV, it's a ***T*** SV, a *tab* separated values file.
Excel won't know that unless you tell it and misinterprets the data.

Comment: sry i used to uploaed the older version, where SU wherent replaced by Direct. This is the actuall form now.    My mssql used to import from this files, and it looks/feels like its the same as excel uses. So i choose excel to show. But the point is, we do this since ever and it worked.. hmm, maybe it's time to change..

Comment: Still, CSV !== TSV. Excel is interpreting the TSV as CSV, is all.